# trying to get thumbnail to appear before post

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

http://news-test.gnome.org/original-posts/

I would like the thumbnail to appear before the title of the post here. I have tried making a list-category-posts folder right under my theme folder, with a new template file called thumb-before-title.php. The only thing I changed from default.php was I placed the

//Post Thumbnail
    $lcp_display_output .= $this->get_thumbnail($single);

right after "Start a list item for each post..." and right before "Show the title and link..."

I then added template=thumb-before-title to my shortcode, but I get an empty page. If I add template=thumb-before-title.php, I get a page of posts, but the thumbnail still appears after the title.

I have tried several other ways to make this work, all to no avail.

What do you suggest? Thank you so very much!

Comment: Could you put the whole `thumb-before-title.php` file? So we could see how the variable `$lcp_display_output` is build?

Comment: voted you up . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why your template changes aren't taking -- it looks like you're doing what you should. If you'd like to fix the problem via CSS, adding these rules to your styles.css file would make that page look nice:

```
.lcp_catlist li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.lcp_catlist li img {
    margin: 5px 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You Rock!!! Guess I should have gone CSS to start with.  I was trying to call the img a thumbnail or post_thumbnail, not getting it right. You got rid of the list style too. This is such a relief. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that messed up the formatting around the images in the content of the posts called on my home page: http://news-test.gnome.org/  I tried messing with the margin to fix that, but can't get it right. Any suggestions? Can we call it something besides img?

Comment: Hmm... if you just need it on that page you could use the Custom CSS plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/safecss/